# Large text in list view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

hi i want to create a list view contain an image and two text view.i create them and checked they working fine when text is small say hello world but when i have large text only one textview is visible.i know its because of linearlayout as the text size increases other textview going to downside so not visible can any one please suggest a layout or guideline tha how to handle large text or vary listview sizes so that when text is arge size of listitem increases and when the size is small size decreases or remain constant.
here is my layout of listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="50px" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/s3" />
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="100px"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello worldjjkljllk;lk;lkklkljkjgfytedtdgihfddgihjghvssetrtyugufgfddfdsafdfugvbcfttyugbhgsdtrrtyvhv"/>
     <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello world"/>
     <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello world"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <CheckBox
    android:layout_width="30px" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is base adapter class.

```
class base extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View v;
            LayoutInflater li=getLayoutInflater();
            v=li.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);

            return v;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use RelativeLayout rather than LiearLayout, and using

```
android:layout_width="100px"
```

is not preferred, try to use density pixel

```
android:layout_width="100dp"
```

or I think you should be better use

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

the width of your layout will be adjusted automatically when the size of your textview become larger.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of PX use DP, this will make it density independent and you will get same size on all type screens.

For more details see http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html